# Specifying a generic parameter in a double list in F#

Tags: f#, generic-collections

I am creating a function in F# which is given a list of lists, and which returns true, if all lists are of the same length, except if this length is 0.

I want to specify that the entries of the inner list can be a generic type `'T`, so I was going for

```
let properTable (input : list list<'T>) : bool =
   let lengths = set ([for i in 0..(input.Length-1) -> input.[i].Length])
   not (lengths.Contains(0)) && lengths.Count = 1
```

When pasting this function into F# interactive, I get the error message:

*stdin(148,35): error FS0010: Unexpected type application  in pattern. Expected ')' or other token.*

If I replace the type the type of `input` with `int list list`, the function works, but I'd like any type, not just an `int`.

I can get it to work with only a single list, as in

```
let testSingleList (input : list<'T>) : bool =
    input.Length > 0
```

How can I accomplish a similar construction, but for a list of lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing two different "styles" of type annotation.

Using either

```
'T list list
```

or

```
List<List<'T>>
```

should work.